# What's the difference manipulating display object position?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have 2 possibilities. It looks like these are the same (or I'm wrong). Which is better and why?

```
 var quest1:DisplayObject = FrameCanvas.baseCanvas.addChild(app.questionmark1); // 
 quest1.x = posX; // 
 quest1.y = posY;   //
```

or

```
 app.questionmark1.x = posX;
 app.questionmark1.y = posY;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example `quest1` is a reference to `app.questionmark1` which you are adding to `FrameCanvas.baseCanvas` and then updating its x and y.

In the second example you are directly setting the x and y on app.questionmark1.

Both work to update `app.questionmark1`'s x and y properties, but in the second example `app.questionmark1` may not be on the stage unless you added it somewhere else in the code.

The second example is better because there's really not a reason to store a reference to `app.questionmark1` as `quest1` as you already can access it by `app.questionmark1`.

Comment: Thanks :) I was looking for such explanation.